# JS - Loop with multi Regex and insert in DataBase

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, regex, loops

hello I have a text document in which I would like to retrieve successive elements at each loop with regex (name, image, url, date) in order to save these data in a database "INSERT INTO event (name, image, url, date) VALUES ('name1', 'image1', 'url1', 'date1')"

- I managed to find the regex but I only manage to make a loop with 1 element at a time (either name, either image, either url or date). Each loop, i want to retreive all element for n°1 and insert in DB, after for n°2 and insert in DB, after for 3....

https://regex101.com/r/WW84R8/2
i want "group 1, group 2, group 3, group 4"

```js
 const regexp = RegExp('","name":"(.+?)","__isS|"image":{"uri":"(.+?)"|"eventUrl":"(.+?)"|"start_timestamp":(.+?),','g');
const matches = str.toString().matchAll(regexp);

for (const match of matches) {
  console.log(`NAME: ${match[0]}`);
  console.log(` -IMAGE:  ${match[1]}`);
 console.log(` -URL: ${match[2]}`);
  console.log(` - DATE: ${match[3]}`);
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be most helpful if you provided that actual string rather than, well, whatever that `str` represents. The `...` doesn't really help us understand the issue you have. Also, the RegEx is not really a pattern that you say you _found_. Please provide the _actual_ string to be parsed along with the _actual_ RegEx pattern you are using. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, i have change the question. The problem is to make a loop with all group of regex and not group1 for fist loop, group2 for second loop, group 3 for third loop...

Comment: Again, without seeing what the string looks like it is impossible to tell what your RegExp is doing. presumably `.matchAll()` should be returning an array of arrays, but it doesn't appear to be doing that since your output is only a single result. That indicates your RegExp is not returning multiple results.

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/vm5PXJ/1

Comment: i have post the regex example

Comment: You know, this looks like a sequence of JSON objects, isn't it? Can you split them somehow and parse with `JSON.parse`? The usual way to handle such corrupt JSONs is to find a way to make them valid JSONs, and parse with the appropriate tool.

Comment: I think you should split the jsons into separate structures using something like `var jsons = str.split(/(?={"data":{)/).filter(Boolean)` and parse each with JSON parser.

Answer (score -1):

it works with

```
"Event","id":"([0-9]+)"(?:.*?)"image":{"uri":"(.*?)"(?:.*?)"eventUrl":"(.*?)"(?:.*?)"start_timestamp":(.*?),
```

https://regex101.com/r/WW84R8/4